# Bulk Insert any Compressed format in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to import a compressed file of .Z format having .txt file. Its size is 37 GB, after un-compression its becomes 240 GB.

Firstly I un-compress the file an it take 6~7 hours and then import to database using export import wizard and it take many and many hours to complete.

I have to perform this activity 5 times a month. It take all resources of the server and is very hectic.

Is there any procedure to or a tool that can import any compressed format directly to database?

I would be very thank full. Its a huge tension for me.
Need help..

Comment: i don't think sql server or any DBMS has the functionality you needed.only option i think is to follow best practices while loading data and see how this can be loaded fast

Comment: SQL2016,introduced compress and decompress functions,you may want to check them to see,if it helps

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy solution for this kind of problem. If this is unacceptable you would have to change how currently you data is received:

- Do not know your data, but maybe you can get differential files (with changes only)?
- Could you receive data more often in smaller chunks?
- Could you connect directly to source system?

Otherwise if data format doesn't change I would create unattended solution to uncompress and load data - then let it run off the working hours (weekend is possible). Then you can try different approaches to load data. Depending on you file/table structure maybe you could use combination of bulk load and partition switching, etc...

Mentioned [COMPRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622775.aspx) & [DECOMPRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622776.aspx) functions from SQL 2016 rather will not help as those functions are ment to be used on columns.

Answer (score 1):

[dba-tools](https://dbatools.io/) powershell utility has this functionality for gzipped `csv` files.

call dba-tools with [Import-DbaCsv](https://docs.dbatools.io/Import-DbaCsv.html).  If the file ends in `.gz`, it'll decompress it on the fly. The import is streamed as well so memory should be kept at a limit.

See Git Issue here regarding gzipped compression:
https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/issues/8554